# Unable to keep background from being covered up

Tags: html, css

Im working on a project for school and I am unable to keep my background from being covered up.  Inside of a div tag I have two columns (left and right)  If I edit the text in right column, it adjusts the background just fine, however if I edit the text in the left column it overflows past the background and into the footer.  I have code if need be, any suggestions as what could be wrong with my html/css?

Here is the html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>///</title>
<link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>



<header> 
    <img alt="Wright State University Logo" src="images/WSU.jpg" />
</header>



<nav class="horizontal">
<ul>
    <li><a href="final_project.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a></li>
    <li><a href="courses.html">Course Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="page_one.html">Important Links</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>



<div id="wrapper">



    <div id="columnleft">

    <aside class="asideleft">
        test test test test test test testtest test test test test test     testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test test

    </aside>
    </div>



    <div id="columnright">

        <img alt="///" src="//////////////////////"/>

        <aside class="asideright">

            <h3 class="h3">Recent News</h3>

            <p>test test test test test test testtest test test test  test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test test test testtest test test test </p>

        </aside>

    </div>



</div>


<footer>&copy; Wright State University
&bull;3640 Colonel Glenn Hwy, Dayton, OH 45435 &bull;cse-dept@wright.edu &bull;
(937) 775-5131</footer>




 </body>

 </html>
```

Here is the css

```
 body{
font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
background-image:url('../images/grid.png');
background-repeat:repeat; 
-webkit-background-repeat:repeat;
-moz-background-repeat:repeat;
-ms-background-repeat:repeat;
}


div#wrapper {
background-color:gold;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: auto;
 }

 header{
width: 980px;
padding-left: 420px; 
 }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
border: 1px solid #FFF;
border-radius: 5px; 
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
}

nav.horizontal{
height:60px;
width:100%; 

}


 nav.horizontal ul li{
border: 2px #006600 solid;
font-size:16px;
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
width:180px;
display:block;
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
text-align:center;
}

 nav.horizontal ul li a{
display:block;
background-color:gold; /*b */
color:RBG(16, 83, 55);
font-size: large;




-webkit-border-radius:30px / 25px;
-moz-border-radius:30px / 25px;
-ms-border-radius:30px / 25px;
text-decoration:none;
}

 nav.horizontal ul li a:hover{
background-color:lightslategrey;
color:#000;
}

nav.horizontal ul li a:visited{
color: RGB(16, 83, 55);
}


 #columnleft{
float: left; 
width: 740px;
margin-top: 13px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 10px;
margin-left: 15px;   
 }

.h3{
border: 3px #FFF solid;
}

 #columnright{
float: none; 
width: 165px; /** sets width of this column to 700px/980px**/
margin-right: 10px;
padding-top: 13px;
padding-left: 810px;
padding-bottom: 5px;

 }

 .asideleft{
background-color: RGB(16,83,55);
border-radius: 5px;
border-color: #FFF;
color:#FFF;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 1px;

}

.asideright{
padding-top: 1px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
background-color: RGB(16,83,55);
border-radius: 5px;
border-color: #FFF;
color:#FFF;
text-align: center;

}   


 footer{
 margin: 0 auto;
width: 980px;
color: #FFF;
font-size: medium;
background-color: gold;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
color:#2E71c0;
margin-top: 10px;


}
```

Comment: you'll need to clear the float on the left column and remove the `float:none` on the right column. Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you need to set the height on the `body` and `html` elements like so:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

[Here is an article](http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/) with more detail.

**EDIT**

Based on your code sample, I see that you are not clearing the `float` rule on the left column. A classic approach has been to add this style rule: `.clear { clear: both; }`, and apply it to an empty `<div>` or `<br>` that is a sibling of the element you are floating.

A more contemporary solution [outlined on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/clear) is to use the `::after` pseudoselector on the wrapping element, like so:

```
#wrapper::after { 
  content: "";
  display: block; 
  visibility: hidden; 
  clear: both;
}
```

In either case you'll need to remove the `float:none` from `#columnright`. Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/ckundo/vNyNY/1/